# How to convert several rows in one row with different selected fields in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have some records that they have a Priority field and I want to select some fields of these records with the highest rank in one record. If the value of the field is null it'd choose the lower priority one.

You can see sample data in the image below: the orange table is the source and the blue one is the result.

[image]

**UPDATE**

```
CREATE TABLE MyView(Id INT ,[Priority] INT ,[F1] INT ,[F2] INT ,[F3]   INT);
INSERT  INTO [dbo].[MyView]
VALUES  ( 15, 4, NULL, 3, 2 ),
        ( 20, 3, 2, 1, NULL ),
        ( 28, 2, NULL, 0, 9 ),
        ( 36, 1, 5, 1, NULL );
DROP TABLE [dbo].[MyView];
```

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: "Higher" and "lower" than what? Did you mean "highest" and "lowest"?

Comment: Thank you @BrankoDimitrijevic, I corrected it :)

Comment: Just as an aside - we don't tend to need the typing practice. The *ideal* way to present sample data is a script that creates a (table/temp table/table variable) and populates it using an `INSERT` statement, shown to us as *code*. So that, rather than having everyone re-typing your sample from the image, we can just copy & paste it into management studio and write our solutions (which we can then easily test also)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks for your helpful tip. I added codes.

Comment: Did you try my query?

Comment: @sagi I found your answer similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045288/find-first-non-null-values-for-multiple-columns/2045398#2045398

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I can't think of anything too efficient for this, but try this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 t.f1,
       (SELECT TOP 1 s.f2 FROM YourTable s
        ORDER BY CASE WHEN s.f2 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
                 s.priority DESC) as f2,
       (SELECT TOP 1 q.f3 FROM YourTable q
        ORDER BY CASE WHEN q.f3 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
                 q.priority DESC) as f3
FROM YourTable t
ORDER BY CASE WHEN t.f1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
         t.priority DESC
```

Comment: I see the question wasnt clear enough but it was excellent answering...

Comment: I agree with you I think there is no better option.