# Merging 2 rows into one in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
(
id integer NOT NULL,
  rank integer,
  col1 text,
  col2 text,
  CONSTRAINT mytable_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);


INSERT INTO mytable(id, rank, col1, col2)  VALUES (1, 1, 'c', 'c');
INSERT INTO mytable(id, rank, col1, col2)  VALUES (2, 2, 'a', 'a');
INSERT INTO mytable(id, rank, col1, col2)  VALUES (3, 2, 'b', NULL);
INSERT INTO mytable(id, rank, col1, col2)  VALUES (4, 3, 'c', 'c');
```

I have to do a query in postgresql 9.0 that "merge" the two rows with equal "rank" value in one row, with these rule:
for col1 and col2, choose the values with highier "id" value, but when this is NULL, choose the other value
(note: rows with equal "rank" value cannot be more than 2)

result expected:

```
rank    col1     col2
------------------------------
1   c   c
2   b   a
3   c   c
```

Comment: LEFT JOIN + COALESCE()

Comment: A pity that [these](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/First/last_(aggregate)) are not builtin.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find first non-null values for multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045288/find-first-non-null-values-for-multiple-columns)

Comment: @forpas It's the first when when ordered by "higher id".

Answer (score 0):

BTW: `rank` is a keyword, I had to rename to `rnk`

---

```
SELECT a.rnk
        , COALESCE(a.col1,b.col1) AS col1
        , COALESCE(a.col2,b.col1) AS col2
FROM mytable a
LEFT JOIN mytable b ON a.rnk = b.rnk AND a.id > b.id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM mytable x
        WHERE x.rnk = a.rnk
        AND x.id > a.id
        )
        ;
```

---

The same, using WINDOW functions:

---

```
SELECT rnk
        ,COALESCE(col1,lead1) AS col1
        ,COALESCE(col2,lead2) AS col2
FROM (
        SELECT rnk,col1,col2
        , rank() OVER (www) AS zrank    -- REVERSED order (per rnk)
        , LEAD(col1) OVER www AS lead1  -- Value for next record , if any
        , LEAD(col2) OVER www AS lead2  -- Value for next record , if any

        FROM mytable
                WINDOW www AS (partition BY rnk ORDER BY id DESC)
        ) xxx
WHERE zrank = 1
        ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
select mt.rank,
       (select col1 from mytable where id = max(case when mt.col1 is not null then mt.id end)) as col1,
       (select col2 from mytable where id =max(case when mt.col2 is not null then mt.id end)) as col2
from mytable mt
group by mt.rank 
order by mt.rank;
```

Another way by using `with` and `self join`

```
with tab as (select rank, 
             max(case when col1 is not null then id end) col1,
             max(case when col2 is not null then id end) col2 from mytable
            group by rank)

select tab.rank "rank", mt1.col1 "col1", mt2.col2 "col2" 
from tab
left join mytable mt1 on mt1.id=tab.col1 
left join mytable mt2 on mt2.id=tab.col2 
order by tab.rank
```